# Finding a location of a file on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have a laptop running Windows 10, and I have a program running yet I can't access the location of that program. It's clear that it's on my list of programs (1.08GB) but I can't trace the location. How can I solve this? Every time I try searching it up, it leads to the appdata folder but I want the Installer.

Answer (score 3):

One simple way to find out what processes are running is with Windows Task Manager. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> simultaneously, and, on the *Details* page, add *Image path name*, if not already visible, by right-clicking on the table caption line and selecting it as shown below.

SysInternals *Process Explorer* can be used the same way.

[image: Task Manager]

Answer (score -2):

Are you looking for the **Installation** file or the **Executable** file? The installation file is NOT linked to the executable file.

To find the executable file (the file used to launch the application .exe) search under
C:\Program Files\ or C:\Program Files (x86)\

Comment: Am looking for the executable file.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)